# Generate integers in SQL without using loops

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to create a table with a column containing integers from 0 to 1000 without using loops?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do it without using loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive [CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression):

```
with recursive n as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from n
      where n < 1000
     )
select n
from n;
```

Comment: is there any way i can get numbers starting from 0 to 999

Comment: You can apply logic in cte or while selecting from cte. Simplest way will be `select n-1 from n`

Comment: @cooldeepcool . . . Or you can use `select 0 as n` as the first part of the recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0):

`CROSS JOIN` will be faster than a recursive CTE ([kudos to Itzik Ben-Gan](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/12/t-sql-queries/number-series-challenge))

```sql
WITH
  L0 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c 
          FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
  L1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B ),
  L2 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B ),
  Nums AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
            FROM L2 )
SELECT rownum - 1 AS n
FROM Nums
ORDER BY rownum
LIMIT 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

---

**Query #1**

```
with recursive numbers(id) as (
   select 0 as id
   union all
   select id+1 from numbers where id < 999
)
select id from numbers;
```

| id |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| . |
| . |
| . |
| 997 |
| 998 |
| 999 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8X8vNhvwQN9pFQ6cAcXhEJ/1)